# Core Data not Persisting

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm having a problem with Core Data. I have a table view `viewcontroller1` that is populated from an array that is populated with data in my Core Data model. When a cell is selected, it does a push segue to `viewcontroller2`, where you can view the saved data. From there, I have button called "edit" that, when selected, does a modal segue to `viewcontroller3` where you can edit that data. Here's the code I have for saving the edited data.

```
//editModel

[self.editModel setValue:self.editNameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
[self.editModel setValue:self.editTextView.text forKey:@"text"];
[self.editModel setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];

NSError *error;
if (![[self.delegate managedObjectContext] save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Can't save the edit: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

if (self.delegate)
    [self.delegate dismissEdit:self];
else
    NSLog(@"There is no delegate");
```

However, whenever I try calling this, I get an NSLog: `Can't save the edit: (null)`

`viewcontroller2` reflects the change; as does the table view in `viewcontroller1`. But, when I quit the iOS Simulator and run it again, I only get data previous to the editing process. Help?

Comment: Is the delegate returning the managed object context?

Comment: @Wain - Yes, it does.

Comment: Checked? Try `[self.editModel.managedObjectContext save:&error]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the managed object context isn't being made available by the `delegate`. Rather than get it from the `delegate`, each managed object has a link to the managed object context that it is added to so you can do:

```
[self.editModel.managedObjectContext save:&error]
```